# Use domain name with multiple IPs in Varnish reverse proxy

Tags: cloud, reverse-proxy, varnish

I am having an issue with my varnish reverse proxy setup.
We have a domain that points to different IPs

```
root@vproxy:~# service varnish restart Message from VCC-compiler:
Backend host "xxx.xxxxxx.net": resolves to too many addresses. Only one IPv4 and one IPv6 are allowed.

Please specify which exact address you want to use, we found all of these:

    128.x.x.1

    128.x.x.2

    128.x.x.3

    128.x.x.4

('input' Line 17 Pos 13)
    .host = "xxx.xxxxxx.net";
------------#################-

Running VCC-compiler failed, exited with 2
 VCL compilation failed  * Syn

tax check failed, not restarting
```

we want varnish to automatically an ip from the multiple ones and use it. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up your backends one by one (or by a domain that has 1 A record). Your question is entirely answered in the varnish documentation: https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/vcl-backends.html

To use multiple backends with the same role, you need to **group** them with Directors (also on the same page in the documentation).

Comment: On my server every week my resellers create almost 3 new domains with different accounts, is there a way to automate it?

Comment: @Luis your question has no usable informaton, it just triggers several other questions. What is a reseller, what do they do, what is an account, what it is that can be/should be automated? Form your question as a post, fill it in with proper information so someone might be able to answer it.

Comment: This answer implies, that there should be a backend for each IPs. Thats not correct. There should be just ONE backend to one of the resolved IPs (doesn't matter which one).

The documentation is only about multiple backends and directors, not about DNS resolution.

Comment: This answer doesn't implies that and was relevant back in 2015 when the error happened. There was a documented feature in Varnish in 2013 that would allow multiple IPs in a hostname and round-robin among the resolved IPs. It just did not work for some reason: https://varnish-cache.org/lists/pipermail/varnish-bugs/2013-August/005649.html). If it works now, then both the error and the answer is irrelevant. I don't get what you mean by __"there should be a backend for each IPs"__. Backend configs have IPs and not the other way around.